# 2 culture settings for same web application?

Tags: asp.net, web-config, cultureinfo

Is it possible to use fr-CA culture setting for dates (franch dates) and en-CA for numbers (period decimal separator) in ASP.NET Web.config?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot mix cultures, but you can create your own culture, see here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172469(v=vs.80).aspx

**To define and create a custom culture**

1. Use a CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder object to define and name your custom culture. The custom culture can be an entirely new culture, or can be a culture that replaces an existing .NET Framework culture or Windows locale.
   For new cultures, you can populate the CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder object properties with an existing CultureInfo object and the LoadDataFromCultureInfo method, and an existing RegionInfo object and the LoadDataFromRegionInfo method. For replacement cultures, the CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder object properties are automatically populated from the properties of the culture being replaced.
2. Modify the properties of the CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder object to satisfy the requirements of your application.
3. Call the Register method to register your custom culture. The registration process performs these tasks: